# How to calculate running time of sql code in DolphinDB

Tags: influxdb, dolphindb

I want to calculate the running time of matrix multiply operation in DolphinDB GUI,

```
x=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
y=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
x**y
```

I try the function timer as bellow,

```
x=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
y=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
tm =timer(x**y)
assert 1,tm < 2000000000
```

Then execute it,the result show as bellow,

```
2019-05-10T17:37:00.359: execution was completed with exception
Syntax Error: [line #3] Cannot recognize the function name timer
```

How to get the running time ?

Answer (score 0):

`timer` is a statement, not a function in DolphindB. To calculate the running time and assign to a variable, please use `now` function.

```
x=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
y=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
start = now()
x**y
tm = now() - start
```

The time precision is millisecond. If you want to get the precision of nanosecond, set the optional argument to true for `now` function.

```
x=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
y=rand(1.0, 1000000).reshape(1000 : 1000)
start = now(true)
x**y
tm = now(true) - start
```